# sheet cannot be found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working macro which changes a linked sheet in a cell according to month. Say from April to March.

From

```
='C:\Data\Name\[Time.xlsx]2021-04!A1"
```

to

```
='C:\Data\Name\[Time.xlsx]2021-05!A1".
```

This works as long as the user remembers to add a new sheet at the beginning of each month, which is not always done in time. As a result i get a "sheet cannot be found -> choose one from below" Prompt". How can I avoid this selector and add a "table not found" string in the cell instead and move on to the next operation in the loop?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Code Added upon request:

```
Sub Month()

Set rngB = Range("B2:B6")
strColB = "Range("B1")
iRowB = 1

strMonth = InputBox ("Insert Month as integer","Month")
strMonth = Trim(strMonth)

For Each cellB In rngB
    cellB.Formula = "='C:Data\[" & strColB & "Time.xlsx]2021-" & strMonth & "'!B" & iRowB
    iRowB = iRowB + 1
Next cellB

End Sub
```

Comment: Added my code - I am aware it's prolly weird, but it has worked so far.

Comment: If you haven't checked it, I added another example to my answer after you added your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy function to test if a sheet exists prior to accessing its cells

```vb
Function SheetExists(ByVal SheetName As String, ByRef InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not InWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Here's how you would use it.

```vb
Sub test()
    MsgBox SheetExists("2021-04", Application.Workbooks("Time.xlsx"))
End Sub
```

Another example:

```vb
Sub test()
    If SheetExists("2021-04", Application.Workbooks("Time.xlsx")) Then
        'do stuff
    Else
        [a1] = "table not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:
After the code was added to the original post. Here is an example of how to implement this function with that code:

```vb
Sub Month()

Set rngB = Range("B2:B6")
strColB = Range("B1").Text
iRowB = 1

strMonth = InputBox("Insert Month as integer", "Month")
strMonth = Trim(strMonth)

For Each cellB In rngB
    If SheetExists("2021-" & strMonth, Application.Workbooks("Time.xlsx")) Then
        cellB.Formula = "='C:Data\[" & strColB & "Time.xlsx]2021-" & strMonth & "'!B" & iRowB
    Else
        cellB.Formula = "table not found"
    End If
    iRowB = iRowB + 1
Next cellB

End Sub
```

Comment: I think it would be good if such functions don't rely on the ActiveWorkbook - maybe add the workbook as parameter.

Comment: @FunThomas I agree, I just didn't want to over-complicate a simple example of how to check if a sheet exists.

Comment: I don't think it's over-complicating it. My 5 cents: *Never* use `Worksheet`, `Cells` or `Range' unqualified. We have by far too many questions on SO where the problem is the very reason that code workes because the assumption of Acticesheet is true, but then one day it fails.

Comment: Maybe i should clarify, that I aggregate data from several different workbooks. Would your function still work then?

Comment: @AdamMcMillan0815 I have modified the function to accept a workbook as a parameter. This way you can specify which workbook you are looking within.